# Arduino selection for RTOS

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, hardware

I am brand new to Arduino and am having a difficult time understanding the "lay of the land". I'm looking for the beefiest, fastest, most compute-centric Arduino available to the market that will run [embox](https://github.com/embox/embox).

As I understand it, there is really only the Uno and the Mega, both of which are 32-bit. However I also believe that 64-bit variations/designs exist and was wondering if anyone has actually implemented Arduino Uno/Mega as a 64-bit MCU. I also see there is the Arduino Due, but not sure how that fairs (beefiness-wise) with Uno/Mega.

So to summarize: **What is the beefiest Arduino one can find, is it 32- or 64-bit, and will it run an embedded RTOS like embox?**

Comment: Why are you looking for something arduino related? the normal AVR arduinos are 8-bit cores packed full of IO, but not intended for doing much calculation.

Comment: I have some teensy boards, that aremore than sufficent, and fully supported by the FOSS, RTOS NuttX. teensy 3.x, 4.x are supported that I know of off hand. you miht find there is arduino stm32 support in which case you can run NuttX on that as well. Check em out: https://nuttx.apache.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I'm not experienced with running an RTOS on it, I'd highly recommend [Teensy 3.1](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) as the "beefiest, fastest, most compute-centric Arduino". FreeRTOS and ChibiOS both support Teensy.

Comment: Thanks @Arvid Jense (+1) - but what exactly is **Teensy**? Is it Arduino? if so, why don't I see "*Arduino Teensy*" anywhere on the [Arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc/) site? Thanks again!

Comment: Teensy is an Arduino compatible board made by Paul Stoffregen and is meant serve for specific applications where you'd want to use the Arduino IDE, but you need more performance than the Atmega chips can deliver, while still being less expensive than most other alternatives. Paul contributes a LOT to the Arduino code base, yet doesn't feel the need to pay for licensing, which is why you won't see it on the arduino website.

Comment: Thanks @Arvid Jense (+1 again) - what about my specific questions though? (a) How does Teensy compare to Arduino Due (which seems to be the beefiest)? (b) Is Teensy 32- or 64-bit? (c) Would Teensy run embox? How can you tell? Thanks again!?

Comment: a) Due's main advantages are that is has more IO pins and has the arduino form factor, Teensy 3.1 on the other hand is a lot cheaper and fits on a breadboard. Otherwise they are very similar, so I really depends on your specific needs.

Comment: b)  32 bit. If you want 64bit you might be looking towards something different than arduino. c) It doesn't seem like it, Google is your best friend!

Comment: Thanks @Arvid Jense (+2 for both!) - last follow up question, I promise! For (c) you said "doesn't seem like it", can I ask why? What makes you think Arduino Due/Teensy won't run embox? Thanks again!

Comment: Check out the [Embox site](https://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/PlatformsDescription) to see what platforms are compatible with embox, Arduino doesn't seem te be in here. The other two RTOS' I linked to did seem to able to run on Arduino.

Comment: Okay @Avrid Jense (+1) - I think **that** is the root of my confusion here. On Embox's site, they mention ARM as a compatible platform...isn't Arduino Due ARM?!? If not, what is it? From the [Due's own website](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue): "*The Arduino Due is a microcontroller board based on the Atmel SAM3X8E **ARM** Cortex-M3 CPU*"....thoughts?

Comment: It might be able to work if you know what to do, but why doesn't the [STM32Discovery](https://code.google.com/p/embox/wiki/PlatformStm32Discovery), which is already supported, suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You could try an [Intel Edison Arduino Kit](https://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelEdison).

It's 64 bit and can be programmed with a variant of the Arduino IDE.
You can interleave Arduino code with system calls to the Linux OS, depending on which approach better suits a specific need.

Running an RTOS inside Edison seems a bit overkill, however it should be doable.

Otoh you could just rely on the much higher clock to provide quasi-deterministic response.

Or just ditch the Arduino IDE and write a normal program with your programming language of choice.